# GCP: Import data into CloudSQL from local drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

If I need to import sql file from my local drive to GCP's CloudSQL Postgres DB, it seems there is no way to do that.

The docs only talk about importing from Google Cloud Storage. Do I have to buy bucket storage just to import data to CloudSQL, or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just connect to your Cloud SQL database using a postgres CLI locally and pipe in your local sql file. It will be slower than importing from a GCS bucket if your data is already, but (probably) faster than uploading to GCS and then importing to Cloud SQL from there.

Although, depending on how large the dump is, it's possible that the local CLI's connection may break in the middle of the upload. This can happen for any number of reasons, and the re-connects implemented in the GCS upload and GCS->Cloud SQL import would prevent this from being a problem. So if your import is larger then tens of GBs, depending on your Internet speed, it might better to temporarily put the dump on GCS and then import it to the database.